# CSS change content with keyframe

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to create a button that rotates on hover for 1s and change it's content during the animation. I'm using [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) and want a delete button that gets turned into an "x" button on hover. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/pnpTL/).

Ideally the animation would also run backwards when unhovering.

So how do I change the content of a pseudo element during an animation?

This is my keyframe animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes {
    0% {
        content:'\f056';
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        content:'\f057';
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(720deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/D2GqH/) that I hope will help you.

CSS

```
.outside {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 10px solid blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    transition: all 3s ease;
    transition-property: transform;
}
.outside:hover {
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
}
```

JS

```
$('.outside').hover(
    function()
      {
       $('.outside').html('X');
       },
    function()
      {
       $('.outside').html('D');
      }
                    );
```